# System requirements

Tags: 12.04, system-requirements

I have AMD Athlon 2600+ (works on 1.9 GHz), 768MB DDR1 ram and Ati Radeon 9500pro 128MB ram. Can I run Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 on this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will run great with this setup.

[Depending on how you use your system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110335/drawbacks-of-using-preload-why-isnt-it-included-by-default), you can use `preload` to make it even faster.

Remember to [install graphics drivers](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers) in order to get maximum performance.

If you are unsatisfied with plain Ubuntu, you can use Kubuntu, Xubuntu, or Lubuntu instead, which will use less of your graphics card (With Kubuntu, you have more control over that, I find).

Comment: Tnx, I appreciate it.