# How to clean "Preload" cache?

Tags: 18.04, preload

I am a new user for Ubuntu, recently I installed [Preload](https://sourceforge.net/projects/preload/) for better performance, and then I got interested how can I clean its cache.

Is there any command to do it, I didn't find any in the internet.

"preload" was installed with command:

```
sudo apt install preload
```

After installing, I checked if its function with command:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/preload/preload.state
```

Comment: Installed Prelaod plugin .. installed into what, installed how. Please update your question with detailed informations.

Comment: @Soren A updated my question, thank for advice.

Comment: As per my answer below you probably want to use `cat /usr/share/gopreload/enabled` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [FOSS article](https://itsfoss.com/improve-application-startup-speed-with-preload-in-ubuntu/):

### What is Preload?

Preload is a daemon application and runs in the background. Preload analyzes the user behavior and tracks what applications are run frequently by the user. Based on these analysis, it predicts what application the user might run next and fetches those binaries and their dependencies into memory and hence increases the startup time of the application.

---

### You can't really clear the cache

You can't really clear the cache but you can disable specific programs from `preload`. As per this [Arch Linux article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Preload):

To disable the loading of a program, remove the appropriate list in `/usr/share/gopreload/enabled` or move it to `/usr/share/gopreload/disabled`.

You should read the whole article!

---

Also of interest to you:

- [Drawbacks of using preload? Why isn't it included by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110335/drawbacks-of-using-preload-why-isnt-it-included-by-default)

Comment: the `gopreload\enabled` and `gopreload\disabled` are for an entirely different program (`gopreload`)! You should read the whole article! For `preload`, check the `exeprefix` and `mapprefix` lines in `/etc/preload.conf`