# My boot time is fairly slow on 19.04. How do I decrease the time?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.04, performance

Here are the (updated) outputs of relevant commands (which I don't understand very much):

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 7.168s (firmware) + 5.096s (loader) + 37.663s (kernel) + 1min 28.089s (userspace) = 2min 18.019s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 28.000s in userspace
```

Second one:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         39.562s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         22.525s udisks2.service
         21.431s dev-sda8.device
         20.934s systemd-journal-flush.service
         19.850s nmbd.service
         18.866s snapd.service
         17.561s networkd-dispatcher.service
         16.925s ModemManager.service
         15.691s accounts-daemon.service
         12.723s fwupd.service
         11.945s avahi-daemon.service
         11.776s thermald.service
         11.769s apport.service
         11.768s gpu-manager.service
         11.588s preload.service
         11.532s rsyslog.service
         11.522s grub-common.service
         11.477s bluetooth.service
         11.466s systemd-logind.service
         11.454s NetworkManager.service
         11.373s wpa_supplicant.service
         11.367s switcheroo-control.service
         11.365s pppd-dns.service
          6.505s quota.service
          6.413s dev-loop9.device
          6.255s dev-loop25.device
          6.152s dev-loop3.device
          5.972s plymouth-read-write.service
          5.737s dev-loop16.device
          5.306s dev-loop1.device
          5.219s dev-loop17.device
          5.162s systemd-udevd.service
          5.104s dev-loop0.device
          5.061s dev-loop2.device
          4.944s dev-loop19.device
          4.850s dev-loop12.device
          4.588s dev-loop20.device
          4.481s dev-loop26.device
          3.522s apparmor.service
          3.383s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
          3.372s dev-loop21.device
          3.372s dev-loop14.device
          3.371s dev-loop11.device
          3.368s dev-loop8.device
          3.366s dev-loop15.device
          3.365s dev-loop10.device
          3.364s dev-loop13.device
          3.363s dev-loop6.device
          3.360s dev-loop4.device
          3.360s dev-loop18.device
          3.358s dev-loop5.device
          3.357s dev-loop7.device
          3.330s dev-loop22.device
          3.294s dev-loop23.device
          3.263s snap-bower-2.mount
          3.201s dev-loop24.device
          3.082s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
          3.076s systemd-resolved.service
          2.932s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AA61\x2d287F.service
          2.799s snap-core-7713.mount
          2.727s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-107.mount
          2.708s smbd.service
          2.633s snap-libreoffice-152.mount
          2.577s gdm.service
          2.503s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-536.mount
          2.345s plymouth-start.service
          2.278s snap-core18-1223.mount
          2.259s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1353.mount
          2.079s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
          2.070s polkit.service
          1.900s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-91.mount
          1.733s snap-core-7917.mount
          1.718s systemd-sysusers.service
          1.686s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-317.mount
          1.640s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.466s upower.service
          1.272s keyboard-setup.service
          1.265s alsa-restore.service
          1.162s grub-initrd-fallback.service
          1.124s snap-scrcpy-174.mount
          1.095s packagekit.service
          1.047s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-94.mount
          1.037s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.012s networking.service
          1.011s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           966ms snap-spotify-35.mount
           960ms systemd-sysctl.service
           959ms snap-spotify-36.mount
           804ms snap-scrcpy-172.mount
           764ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           734ms kerneloops.service
           627ms systemd-journald.service
           583ms systemd-random-seed.service
           579ms systemd-rfkill.service
           569ms dns-clean.service
           545ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
           477ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           459ms bolt.service
           453ms snap-whatsdesk-15.mount
           451ms snap-core18-1192.mount
           339ms snap-libreoffice-154.mount
           336ms ifupdown-pre.service
           313ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           312ms ufw.service
           311ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           250ms snapd.seeded.service
           227ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-544.mount
           216ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-73.mount
           214ms console-setup.service
           180ms snap-whatsdesk-17.mount
           155ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-359.mount
           152ms user@1000.service
           138ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           136ms openvpn.service
           134ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           121ms boot-efi.mount
           121ms dev-hugepages.mount
           116ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-97.mount
           112ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            92ms snapd.socket
            88ms setvtrgb.service
            85ms rtkit-daemon.service
             9ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
             6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             5ms dev-mqueue.mount
             5ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

I removed the wrong swap info from initramfs, as I removed my swap space and now I have commented the swap line from `/etc/fstab`. These outputs are after that change. My laptop has an Nvidia1050 mobile if that in any way affects this. I have a dual-boot with Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 19.04.

Critical chain -

```
graphical.target @1min 28.000s
└─multi-user.target @1min 28.000s
  └─smbd.service @1min 8.232s +2.708s
    └─nmbd.service @48.378s +19.850s
      └─network-online.target @48.255s
        └─network.target @48.253s
          └─NetworkManager.service @36.798s +11.454s
            └─dbus.service @36.796s
              └─basic.target @36.473s
                └─sockets.target @36.473s
                  └─snapd.socket @36.380s +92ms
                    └─sysinit.target @36.305s
                      └─apparmor.service @30.117s +3.522s
                        └─local-fs.target @30.116s
                          └─boot-efi.mount @29.994s +121ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AA61\x2d287F.service @27.026s +2.932s
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AA61\x2d287F.device @27.025s
```

Comment: The only obvious one: get an ssd. sda8 is a normal harddisk. also mysql: does that need to be loaded on boot?

Comment: I did use that post, but nothing helped me. Even disabling networkmanager-wait-online. Removing mysql right away as it is of no use to me anymore

Comment: Updated the post with new edits, the time is almost the same. Please check!

Comment: You have `preload` installed. You can remove it with `sudo apt remove preload`. This should reduce boot time a bit. Please read here for more info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110335/drawbacks-of-using-preload-why-isnt-it-included-by-default