# Apps are starting up extremely slow - fresh install Ubuntu

Tags: startup

After booting up, almost every app I startup takes 20-40 seconds to load. This is a fairly new gaming laptop. I know it's not the hardware. Please let me know what info I can produce to be helpful. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: HOW MUCH GB RAM DO YOU HAVE

Comment: I have 8gb of RAM

Comment: You have 24 snap packages. They may slowdown boot. Do you use HDD or SSD?

Comment: It's an HDD but a dual boot, linux is running off the internal SSD. Fairly new laptop. Windows doesn't have this issue for what it's worth.

Comment: @N0rbert what does the boot slowdown have to do with clicking an app AFTER it's booted up (logged in)? (Not being rude, just wondering how that all works.)

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and Ubuntu 20.10, on a  Lenovo Legion gaming laptop, on a desktop running i7-7700HK, both with >=16GB RAM. Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have 8gb ram then you can install `preload`

Preload save the sofwares that you use most on ram so that if you click on that next time it will open much faster than hdd or sadd

to install preload paste this command in terminal

```
sudo apt install preload
```

and that's it you dont have to do anything after that just use your pc it will do it work after some time maybe 2 hour of use

Comment: Are there drawbacks to using preload? If I remove all my snaps and just install with apt will that help things? Also, my biggest complaint at the moment is firefox taking 30 sec to start up. And that was preinstalled with Ubuntu, not a snap. I guess preload would just bake FF in to load up faster. Thanks!

Comment: Drawbacks of using preload https://askubuntu.com/questions/110335/drawbacks-of-using-preload-why-isnt-it-included-by-default