# How do I fix high memory usage on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, ram, memory-usage

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS is using a lot of memory, (10.1GB out of 12GB of RAM). The RAM fills up over time and reaches dangerously high levels of usage, even when I am using only 2 applications.

I've tried to follow the other suggestions posted on this forum about similar issues. I've run `htop` and `top` but they don't return useful information, ie it shows Chrome and Discord using the most amount of RAM - just 2-4% each. Java, MySQL, Apache, I've read are usually the culprits of high RAM usage, but Java isn't even running, and the other listed processes are barely using 0.1% of RAM.

Another thing I've noticed is, upon closing Chrome, the memory usage instantly drops from 10.1GB to only 1.7-2GB of usage. I dont understand this because according to `htop`, Chrome is using only 2% or so of memory.

2-4% should not be hogging up the entire memory, so I ran `free -m` and found out that `buff/cache` and `shared` usage is very high - **8.8GB and 7.2GB respectively**. What are these and why are they using up so much memory? The system freezes and behaves very slowly during use. CPU usage is not very high either - hitting a max of 22% occasionally.

Here are my `free -m` results

[image: free -m]

On opening System Monitor,

[image: System Monitor]

My `htop` and `top` results respectively,

[image: htop]

[image: top]

As mentioned before, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Kernel version is `5.11.0-41-generic`

Please help. My computer is becoming increasingly difficult to use.

Comment: @someone Well to be honest, I haven't had this problem before. I used to use 20.04 before there were some disk corruptions and I had to reinstall the operating system fresh. I've only faced this issue after the reinstall but I can't understand how because I'm using the same programs that I used before the reinstall. I don't understand how swap memory is suddenly become an issue when I never had this kind of problem before

Comment: Open the processes tab in system monitor, and check which process consumes the highest memory.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Chrome, with about 329MB (while using 12 tabs, but I've never had this issue of high memory usage before, even while using 20 tabs)

Comment: ok, so IDT swap willl work

Comment: Look at the `VIRT` collomn. There is a lot of cached stuff there.

Comment: You will have to debug yourself: it seems that something is filling cache memory. Reboot your system, open `top` and set the terminal on top, then use your computer and keep an eye on what happens. That may allow you to identify when it happens.

Comment: Alright @vanadium I will try this and get back

Comment: Alright, I tried @vanadium 's suggestion and I couldn't really find out much. I just saw cached memory increase drastically. Then some time later I remembered that I had installed `preload`, which, if I remember correctly is a daemon which determines the most used applications and then preloads them in RAM. I don't think I had preload configured properly. As a result, it appears to have cached too much. I decided to uninstall preload, and after a reboot, the issue seems to have been solved.

Comment: thanks for this @Devvrath. if that worked, could you explain the how to of your solution replying to you own question please?

Answer (score 0):

Copying @Devvrath's comment into an answer, since it is 3 years old now and has not been converted yet.

@Devvrath had installed the `preload` package, after uninstalling the package their issue disappeared.

`preload` is a daemon that monitors/analyzes the applications users run, and tries to keep data in cache to improve the startup time of these applications.

From [documentation of preload](http://behdad.org/preload.pdf)  (emphasis mine):

> The default values for the memory usage formula result in:
>
> max (0,−10% × model.memtotal + 100% × model.memfree) + 30% × model.memcached
>
> which essentially means: **use all free memory except for ten percent of
> total memory**, and thirty percent of memory already used for caches.
> When a system is in steady state, there is little free memory
> available since the kernel utilizes most of the free memory for
> caching. During boot time on the other hand, there is little cached
> memory and a lot of free memory. Given this, the model.memfree and
> model.memcached controls enable tuning preload’s aggressiveness during
> boot process and steady state fairly separately.

As indicated by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/289474/1768993), a potential drawback of `preload` is that the RAM it consumes takes away from the pool of "unused" RAM that the kernel could otherwise use for its own caching purposes. Depending on your particular situation/usage patterns (and the tuning of `preload`'s configuration parameters), `preload` might help or harm performance.